# Serenity: "Which, she would be sleepy" -- why this line?

Tags: firefly, serenity

I have never understood this line. Why did Mr. Universe say this? Is it just some goofy thing or does he mean, perhaps, that after the huge fight, she would be tired?

EDIT: Maybe it is just the punctuation, verbally, that threw me -- If he said it like "Which she would be: sleepy." The comma after the "which" -- that's how he said it -- was weird.

Now if he had said, "Of course, she would be sleepy." I would not have asked the question.

But the cool thing about Firefly is how they suggest language would change -- I loved the occasional Mandarin thrown in, iirc at least sometimes without subtitles. And words like "shiny" -- maybe there are some other examples.

And perhaps this strange way of saying stuff was a deliberate attempt to show how language had changed -- maybe even a professional linguist as technical adviser suggested this.

Comment: You answered your own question :-)

Mr Universe: [Watching the recording of the bar fight] You guys always bring me the very best violence.
[They watch the rest of the fight, which ends with Simon shouting a safe word that causes River to lose consciousness]
Mr Universe: ...And she falls asleep. Which, she would be sleepy.

Comment: To get a real answer, you might want to migrate to English Language and Usage. Questions like "Is this construction standard in any variety of English?" are fairly common over there.

Comment: i can say as a native speaker of english for almost 60 years that was something i had not heard before.

Comment: "maybe there are some other examples." I believe in the episode "Heart of Gold" (maybe?) Nandi asks Mal if he is 'sly', which is 'Verse slang for 'gay', or maybe 'gay on the DL,' which I thought was pretty cool.

Comment: i was thinking how lazy by comparison Star Trek is about evolution of English -- and yet: the actually made up Klingonese and Vulcan. But Star Trek missed many things while be amazing in other areas.

Comment: I've heard the word "which" used that way colloquially before - as just a freeform reference to the previous sentence. As in "He asked me if I ever called them back. Which, I called them twice." It's grammatically unsound, but not unheard of in speech.

Comment: @MishaR: Interesting. I have lived in multiple states in USA and never encountered this but of course there are some weird regional accents and usages even now (Boston accent for example was a real barrier sometimes even though I think it is going away due to TV/Internet/movies and people moving around -- but about 30 years ago someone told me that ordering a "Large milk" in a restaurant was a problem until he said, "Laahge") -- where did you encounter this usage of "which"?

Comment: @releseabe I spend most of my time in the northeastern US, but I cannot give you a lot of detail about where I've heard it. It's not exactly the kind of question where you can respond with "I've heard someone talk this way two years ago in New York" or some such. It isn't memorable enough for that, it just looks familiar - which, if anything, means that I've heard it on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 4):

I always got the impression that she'd be sleepy because she just tore up a bar and fought a lot of people thus making her pretty tired.

Fighting is a high energy consumption activity after all

Comment: yes, as i edited my question, i just think he said it weirdly.

Comment: Yeah in my head its more like "Which *to be fair*, she would be sleepy"

Comment: exactly. i also just changed my question to suggest that along with words like "shiny" this was also an example of what english might be like in 500 years.

Comment: A lot of people on this and other sites phrase their questions in ways that seem rather strange to me, making me suspect that maybe English isn't their first language or maybe I might be a few hundred years older than I think and out of touch with modern English.